# Traversing an XML file using YUI 2.8 library

Tags: xml, yui, yui-datasource

I have a requirement to parse/traverse an XML file using the YUI 2.8 library. From the YUI's manual page of [DataSource](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/), I could get info about how to get the XML file using XHRDataSource and then set the response type and response schema (understood it after so many readings :P ).

But, after setting up the DataSource, I don't know what to do to fetch data from my XML file? [That page](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/) doesn't seem to provide any example on that. can anyone explain the procedure to parse the XML file using DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up your DataSource, call sendRequest() with a callback function to retrieve data from your XML file.

```
var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("./myxml");
myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_XML;
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    resultNode: "book",
    fields: ["title","author","year"]
};
ds.sendRequest(null, {
    success: function(request, response) {
        var results=response.results,
            i=0,
            l=results.length;

        for(; i<l; i++) {
            YAHOO.log(results[i].title);
        }
    }
});
```